# Why a button in LWC component vanishes when its running in the debug mode but the same is shown in the normal mode?

Tags: lwc

Why a button in LWC component vanishes when its running in the debug mode but the same is shown in the normal mode

```
<lightning-button-stateful
      variant={showButtonVariant}
      selected={isButtonDisabled}
      label-when-off="Add"
      label-when-on="Added"
      disabled={isButtonDisabled}
      title="Add account"
      onclick={handleAddClick}
      class="slds-m-left_x-small"
    ></lightning-button-stateful>
```

Button is working fine in the mode where debug is not enabled. But when debug mode is enabled for the user, then it is not shown.

Comment: There must be javascript code that you might be using that is not in sync when its running in the debug mode as there cache is disabled. Please check for that.